# Which is the correct method of outputting numbers, based on the count of strings in a list<>

Tags: c#, html, loops, blazor

I am trying to loop through a collection, to get the total count of items, and
append the numbers to each item.

So for instance, there is two items in my collection.

@QuizItem.QuitTitle holds two strings, what i am trying to achieve is
Loop through the collecion, outputting the amount of items...

i.e

1. Music
2. English

My Code -

```
 @foreach (var QuizItem in QuizDetails)
    {

        @for (int i = 1; i < indexCount; i++)
         {
                 indexCount = i;

             {
                <p style="font-weight:bolder">@indexCount @QuizItem.QuizTitle</p>
             }

         }
```

And in OnInitialized() method

```
indexCount = QuizDetails.Count();
```

The above brings back no results..

If i take out the forloop i get my questions presented.. But obviously the
count is showing 2 on both questions...

Example below

[image]

I have tried many of different ways, but to no avail. I just would like for it to say 1 and 2 respectively by the titles, instead of 2 and 2.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `indexCount` with `QuizDetails.Length`? And remove the `indexCount`, you shouldn't be needing it...

Comment: Have you worked through what will happen in a loop?  specifically, what will happen when you set `indexCount = i` ?  Get a pen & paper and work out an iteration of a loop...

Comment: @Pieterjan can't do that as QuizDetails is a type List<Model> so it does not contain a definition for length

Comment: I am trying to get my head around that bit @devlincarnate. been stuck on this for about 4 hours, driving me insane. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you just need one loop.

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing to me.  You say, "I am trying to loop through a collection, to get the total count of items, and append the numbers to each item."  First, your example is clearly *prepending* (or *prefixing*) the number.  Is that what you meant to say?  Second, your example also shows the current *index* (1-based) prepended to each item, rather than the total count (which would obviously be a constant number, not incrementing as per your example)

Comment: In sinple terms, i have two items in @quizitem.quiztitle i am trying to append the numbers to my titles.. i.e 1. title, 2. title

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop, it tends to work much better in Blazor. If you need a counter, a scoped variable that you `++` in the body of the loop will serve

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue anyway, hopefully it may help, some one in the future.

```
@foreach (var QuizItem in QuizDetails)
    {

        @for (int i = 0; i <= indexCount; i++)
        {
            //indexCount = i;
            if (i == 0)
            {
                i++;
                if (temp == 0)
                {
                    temp = i;
                }

                @for (int b = temp; b <= indexCount; b++ )
                {

                 {
                        <p style="font-weight:bolder">@b @QuizItem.QuizTitle</p>
                        if (temp <= indexCount)
                        {
                            temp++;
                            break;
                        }
                 }
            }
         }

    }
```

temp is a int value, that i initialize at 0..